# Unable to do SSH to remote Server. Error : ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

```
I have changed the file sshd_config under /etc/ssh/ directory. I have also changed the permission of files under /etc/ssh/ directory. Now when i am trying to execute

ssh username@remoteserverIP -vv 
I am getting below logs.

OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "server IP" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to server IP [server IP] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I do not have access to root user. I have also tried via putty. Putty is giving below error.

**Server unexpectedly closed network connection**

Comment: what has this got to do with java?

Comment: I removed tag JAVA

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking questions like this on [unix.se], [sf], or [su] rather than here. Also, "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" is a pretty common error message. You should be able to search for it and find other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps `/etc/hosts.deny` contains an entry for "`ALL:`" or "`ssh:`" preventing you to connect.

Adding "`ssh: ALL`" or "`ssh: x.x.x.x`" (replacing x.x.x.x with your IP) to `/etc/hosts.allow` could resolve this issue.